# Convert date into a specific format in python irrespective of the input format is

Tags: python, datetime, python-dateutil

I have a problem statement to convert the dates into a specific format. However, the input can be of any format.
For example,

| Input | Desired_output |
| --- | --- |
| 2020/11/20 | 2020-11-20 |
| 20201120 | 2020-11-20 |
| 20202011 | 2020-11-20 |
| 11/20/2020 | 2020-11-20 |
| 202020Nov | 2020-11-20 |

I'm able to solve where is a delimiter present in between year, month and date using the Dateutil package. But it is not able to solve where is no clear delimiter.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: there's more to the problem than dateutil's parser complaining... e.g. "20201120" vs. "20202011" might be obvious but how do you differentiate "20200605" vs. "20200506"?

Comment: I don't think there's a way to parse dates universally. You have carefully picked input strings that can be interpreted unambiguously, but "03-04-20" could be 3Apr20 or 4Mar20 depending on the country. And for your last example, `202020Nov`: which 20 is the 20th of the month and which is the YY of `2020`? Consider an ambiguous input, is `202021Nov` 20Nov21 or 21Nov20? If you can't tell, then there's no way you could write a program to tell.

Comment: I agree that there are some ambiguous cases where date is less than 13 and for those cases I can provide a default format to be followed. But at least I want to solve for those obvious cases where there is a clear distinction between year, month and date

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is an easy way to universally parse dates that don't follow the [standard formats](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/%7Emgk25/iso-time.html). You'll have to specify the format in which the date is written for it to be parsed, which you can easily do using [`strptime`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strptime) (see [here](https://strftime.org/) for a reference on datetime formatting).

A package like `dateutil` can be helpful as well. You should take a look, however, at the [accepted date formats](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html#parse-examples). In general, `dateutil` is more convenient, but `strptime` gives you more control and ability to parse more date formats.

Four out of the five examples you mentioned can be parsed using `dateutil` as follows:

```
from dateutil import parser
parser.parse("2020/11/20")   # Output: datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 20, 0, 0)
parser.parse("11/20/2020")   # Output: datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 20, 0, 0)
```

For the two other examples, the [`dayfirst` and `yearfirst` arguments](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html#dateutil.parser.parse) are needed to let `dateutil` parse them correctly:

```
parser.parse("20201120", yearfirst=True)
parser.parse("20202011", yearfirst=True, dayfirst=True)
# Output for both: datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 20, 0, 0)
```

Finally, I'm not aware of a way to parse the date `"202020Nov"` using `dateutil`; however, it can be parsed using `strptime` as follows:

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.strptime("202020Nov", "%Y%d%b")
# Output: datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 20, 0, 0)
```

All the best.